# Can we ever achieve Turing completeness?

Tags: turing-machines, programming-languages, halting-problem, turing-completeness

I want to relate **Turing completeness** to the **Halting Problem**.

As far as I know we say something is turing complete (eg: a programming language) when it can compute any function and can do any task. But since **Halting Problem** can't be solved by any programming language so every programming language should be **Turing Incomplete**. Right?

But every where in internet it's written that modern programming languages like **c++** are **Turing Complete**. Are they wrong or Did I Misunderstood something?

Comment: A machine is not turing complete if it can solve the halting problem, in fact it shows that turning machines can not solve the halting problem.

Comment: Why do you think the halting problem can be solved in every programing language? It's trivial to solve create a program in any language such that if it halts is unknown (eg. the colatz conjecture)

Comment: That's not Turing completeness. Turing completeness is any machine that can emulate a Universal Turing Machine. With the exception of having infinite memory (a theoretical Universal Turing Machine has infinite memory) all general purpose CPUs ever designed, built and sold can emulate a Universal Turing Machine - they're all Turing Complete.  The computer you wrote this question on is definitely Turing Complete (minus having infinite memory)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> As far as I know we say something is turing complete (eg: a programming language) when it can compute any function and can do any task.

No. A [model of computation](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation) is [*Turing-complete*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) if it can compute any *Turing-computable function* (i.e., any computable function that *can be computed by a [Turing Machine](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)*).

An alternative, but exactly equivalent way to phrase it, is that a model of computation is Turing-complete if it can *simulate any Turing Machine*.

Another equivalent way is that a model of computation is Turing-complete if it can *simulate a [Universal Turing Machine](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine)* (which is just a Turing Machine which can simulate any other Turing Machine).

Yet another way to phrase it is that a model of computation is Turing-complete if it can *simulate another Turing-complete model of computation*. This is, in fact, how most Turing-complete models of computation are proven to be Turing-complete. Usually, the proof is not done using Turing Machines but using some other, more mathematically "simple" Turing-complete model of computation such as [Rule 110](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110), [Conway's Game of Life](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), [Cyclic Tag Systems](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_tag_system) or other [Tag Systems](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_system#Turing-completeness_of_m-tag_systems), or even by implementing an interpreter for a simple Turing-complete programming language such as [Brainfuck](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

> But since Halting Problem can't be solved by any programming language so every programming language should be Turing Incomplete. Right?

The [Halting Problem](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is [undecidable](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem), which means the function $\mathit{Halts}(P, i)$ cannot be computed by a Turing Machine. That is the whole point of the Halting Problem.

Since $\mathit{Halts}(P, i)$ cannot be computed by a Turing Machine, it is irrelevant for determining Turing-completeness.

Note that Turing-completeness *only* refers to *computable functions on the natural numbers*. It does not refer to non-computable functions (such as $\mathit{Halts}(P, i)$), and it does not refer to operations which are not functions (such as printing, reading from a keyboard, launching a nuclear missile, etc.).

Also note that, according to the [Church-Turing Thesis](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis), the terms "effectively calculable", "computable", and "Turing-computable" are the same thing, meaning that everything that can be computed by a physically implementable machine *at all* can be computed by a Turing Machine, and, additionally, that the "intuitive" notion of "computable" is the same as the *formal* notion of "can be computed by a Turing Machine". Furthermore, this means that no model of computation that can be physically implemented can be more powerful than a Turing Machine.

So, in this *particular* sense, we can say that "something is Turing-complete if it can compute everything that can be computed at all". But that does *not* mean "compute any function" or "do any task".

But again, keep in mind that this only applies to computable functions on the natural numbers. For example, C++ can print to the screen, which a Turing Machine cannot. But that does not mean that C++ is more computationally powerful than a Turing Machine.

Some people have jokingly coined the term "Tetris-complete" or "Pacman-complete" to describe a programming language which can draw to the screen, receive asynchronous, interactive, input events, interact with the operating system, call third-party and system libraries, model the passage of time, etc. In other words: a programming language which can be used to implement real-world, interactive, macOS/Windows/Linux/Android/… (GUI) applications.

Most real-world programming languages are both Turing-complete and Tetris-complete, whereas the models of computation we are often talking about when discussing Turing-completeness are often not Tetris-complete: e.g., Turing Machines, λ-calculus, Rule 110, Tag Systems, etc.

OTOH, it is possible to have a programming language which is not Turing-complete but Tetris-complete. For example, it is possible to model event-driven interactivity as finite co-recursion over co-data rather than infinite recursion over data.

Comment: Additional info: The OP is probably referring to the common saying that "A Turing Machine can calculate any algorithm". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine which came from Turings proof that "a Turing Machine can calculate any sequence" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine This is NOT the same as "can do any task"

Comment: Thanks. I expanded on some of the points.

Comment: Re: things like "print to the screen" and other real-world engineering considerations: a fun term for that is "Tetris complete" - if the language and system can run the game Tetris, which has real-time performance and timing/delay requirements, graphics, and interactive keyboard input for single keypresses.

Comment: If _launching a nuclear missile_ is a side-effect of your function it should most definitely be documented!

Comment: @PeterCordes: I used that term here https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/64038/6729 and here https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/86171/6729, thanks for reminding me of that term! Indeed, that seems a good addition. (Unfortunately, I mis-rembered: Brady calls Idris *Pac-man complete*, not "Tetris-complete". And in good CS fashion, this has been proven by implementing Space Invaders and arguing that you can reduce one to the other.)

Comment: I wonder if your answer are where I first saw that term... those are both ones I'd already upvoted, probably via hot network questions when the questions were new.

Comment: I found the line "everything that can be computed by a physically implementable machine at all can be computed by a Turing Machine" interesting.  I admit to not having written everything Turing, Church, et. al. wrote, but I don't remember anything about "physically implementable."  Is there a paper you would recommend to read regarding the argument that no physically implementable machine can compute something a Turing machine cannot?  That sounds interesting.

Comment: @CortAmmon . Section 9  of Turing’s On Computable Numbers paper gives an argument that a Turing machine can compute any sequence that a “computer” could.  (Of course “computer” at the time meant a person who computes.) His arguments also applies to machines.  It’s the converse that bothers me. A physical realization of a Turing-complete machine could potentially eventually run out of mass in a finite universe, at which point, it will cease to follow the mathematical model.

Comment: @CortAmmon: I believe that is one of the more modern interpretations of what it means to be "effectively calculable". In Turing's times, this was interpreted to mean "what a mathematician can do with pen and paper", but there is a more modern interpretation that basically says "does not break the laws of physics", e.g. does not violate causality, a finite lower bound on the size of parts, a finite upper bound on the speed of communication, etc. It provides a nice intuition about what the qualitative difference is between all the different Turing-complete models and the Hyper-Turing models.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: Please double check everything in this answer, because I am no expert on the topic.*

The Halting problem is not a necessary condition for Turing completeness. On the contrary: the Turing machine itself cannot solve the halting problem. If You did build a "machine" that *could* solve the halting problem for Turing machines, it would be, at least in that sense, *more* powerful than a Turing machine. It would be unlike anything that we think of as computers. It would be "magic".

So what does a programming language have to do to be Turing complete? It has to be able to simulate a Turing machine. To prove that, it is sufficient to write a program that simulates any Turing complete "machine", e.g. [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

So is C++ Turing complete? Yes but it is complicated. A Turing machine has an infinitely long Tape of memory. C++ on the other hand is very much designed for finite memory. Address pointers use a fixed number of bits, which is determined at compile-time at the latest. So you cannot simply use a (doubly) [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) to simulate the tape. In other languages with a more abstract memory reference model, like Java, this is very much possible.

So how can You prove that C++ is Turing complete? You can show that any program written in lambda calculus can be translated to C++. It is not quite a simple one-to-one translation because in C++ you will have to make some [extra efforts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777354/y-combinator-in-javascript) to make recursion lazy. That being said that is enough to prove that C++ is Turing complete. All you need now is a computer with infinite memory with an instruction set that allows infinite recursion and a compiler that compiles to that architecture...

Fun fact: C++ is even Turing complete during compilation thanks to [template-level programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189172/c-templates-turing-complete). One implication is that we cannot even determine if compilation halts.

The memory limit is, of course, more of a theoretical limitation. Writing a range of length $n$ bits to the tape, the Turing machine requires at least $n$ iterations. To write to an infinite amount of memory takes an infinite amount of time. Ain't nobody got time for that! Alternatively, You could run the machine at an infinite clock frequency, in which case you will likely run into [physical limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units). So for our finite lives, finite memory is just fine.

Comment: It’s an excellent answer.  One quibble is that your argument that you can’t represent an unbounded tape in C++ also applies to lambda expressions, which could grow to any size.  I like that you present Java as being a better example of a Turing-complete language — although for Java you’d have to change the semantics of new, so that it can’t throw an out of memory error.

Comment: Are You sure? Somehow I thought as long as You avoid any pointers or memory addresses, e.g. as seen in this [CppCon Lightning Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hwRxW99lg0), then you *should* be able to build a specialized compiler that can handle it. In practice You are absolutely right of course.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the Java runtime, not the language, decides when to throw an OutOfMemoryError. I can run the same byte code on a 32 bit and a 64 bit machine and it  can use all the memory (e.g. using linked lists). So all You have to do is to build a JVM with pointers of variable bit-length and Your byte code should run just fine on countably infinite memory.

Comment: (a) No, I’m not sure.  By using  C++ lambdas and capturing values, it seems plausible.  I hadn’t thought of that. (b) Yes.  A JVM implementation that never throws a memory out of bounds error would be Turing complete, but Java is not Turing complete, as it’s specification allows new to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

- no machine can solve the Halting problem, this is a mathematical impossibility.
- a system is called Turing-complete when it is able to simulate a Turing machine.

---

It is an easy matter to program a Turing machine in C. Strictly speaking, anyway, the simulation cannot be perfect because a physical system does not have infinite resources.

Comment: It's certainly a short answer. But it doesn't really seem to explain what's wrong with the syllogism in the question.

Comment: Bullet 1 isn't correct. There is no proof that no machine can solve the halting problem; just that no Turing machine can. It is conjectured that no machine can, but not proven.

Comment: @OscarSmith: in fact, all the discussion rests on what we call a machine. I didn't want to clutter my answer with Church's thesis.

Answer (score -1):

The if-statement alone is fully Turing complete for any computation that can be performed, so while it would not be efficient or pretty you could write any program purely with if-statements.  I think that a lot of the meaning around this term has kind of taken on a sort of extended meaning that is more like saying "can this computer write a program as if it were human" or some variation of A.I. is implied.  The simple fact of the matter is that A.I. is not physically or logically possible at least within a digital computer system.  The requirement of every computer is to have a predictable instruction set which is mutually exclusive to free will or arbitrary behavior, they can not mix without destroying the thing that makes it "a computer" in the first place.

Regarding the halting problem, it can be solved by any program that has the potential to be halted, it is just not something we can easily forecast or reduce the computational work so as to run a simulator in fast-forward, but in their own time each program will solve it's halting status or run indefinitely, we just can't look ahead in time with that type of problem because it's inputs and conditions rely on unknown future conditions, so it is inherently a necessarily expensive computation to perform when determining if a program will encounter a deadlock or crash.

You could design a language that has this capability to know it's future halting status or potential, but in creating the bounds needed to construct that type of language we would need to remove it's turing completeness to some degree so that it operates within a finite set of possible conditions... the trade off is diversity in the language's complexity for ability of the compiler to forecast something like a halting condition.

Comment: Any model of computation without some equivalent of loops or recursion cannot be Turing-complete because there are a finite number of paths through the computation.

Comment: The thing about `if` almost right. The actual correct statement is: the instruction `goto x if --y <= 0` is fully Turing Complete. That single instruction has been proven to be able to add numbers together, to generate primes and most importantly you can implement a Universal Turing Machine using a CPU/language with only that instruction.